# Class Generics break completely separate method

Tags: java, generics

I found a strange problem when I used class Generics Today: Setting some broke a completely separate method.

Here's a small example class that illustrates the problem. This code works just fine

```
public class Sandbox {
    public interface ListenerManagerTest {
        public Set<Listener> getListeners();
    }

    public void setListenerManager(ListenerManagerTest listenerManager) {
        for (Listener curListener : listenerManager.getListeners())
            return;
    }
}
```

Now as soon as I use class Generics, the `getListeners()` method returns `Set<Object>` instead of `Set<Listener>`

```
public class Sandbox {
    public interface ListenerManagerTest<E extends Object> {
        public Set<Listener> getListeners();
    }

    public void setListenerManager(ListenerManagerTest listenerManager) {
        for (Listener curListener : listenerManager.getListeners()) //Expected Listener, not Object
            return;
    }
}
```

What would cause this error? The `##java` channel on Freenode said it was because of compile time candy and that I was using a raw type. But how would an raw class type break all generics in the class? And how would of worked before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using raw type (i.e. `ListenerManagerTest` instead of `ListenerManagerTest<...>`) disables generics for all its members, so that `public Set<Listener> getListeners()` is treated as `public Set getListeners()`, therefore you can't iterate it without additional cast.

Use parameterized type instead of raw type (with wildcards if needed):

```
public void setListenerManager(ListenerManagerTest<?> listenerManager) { ... }
```

It's done for backward compatibility. Imagine that you need to make legacy non-generic class generic. In this case legacy code that doesn't know anything about generics still can use that class as a raw type and doesn't require changes. However, that legacy code also doesn't know about generic types of members of that class, so it makes sense to treat them as raw types by default.

Here is an example of legacy code that would be broken after adding generics to `ListManagerTest` class without this rule:

```
public void addListenersToTest(ListenerManagerTest listenerManager, Set listeners) {
    listenerManager.getListeners().addAll(listeners);
}
```

Generally speaking, the concept of raw type was introduced for backward compatibility, and it's not recommended to use raw types without need. That's why raw types have these strange compatibility-related features.

Comment: Why would it do that though? E and Listener are 2 completely separate Generic types, yet E is stepping on everything else.

Comment: Oh and I found out about the `<?>` before I posted the question. I was more asking for the *why* than the *how*

Comment: I don't find the explanation of backwards compatibility compelling.  You could easily still link against a method with a generic return type if you assigned the result to a raw type.

Answer (score 0):

JLS3 4.8 Raw Types

> The superclasses ... of a raw type are the erasures of the superclasses ...
>
> The type of ... instance method ... of a raw type C ... is the erasure of its type...

It is unnecessarily harsh, as your example shows.

Why? I guess at one point, they just throw their hands in air and give up. Generics is too damn complicated, it's too hard to make everything right. Raw type is probably where they can take a rest and be sloppy - with the excuse that we treat raw types as bastards anyway.